# Spring Singleton means no data sharing at class level?

Tags: java, spring

I am confused.

Spring's default bean scope is Singleton. That means that once you define a bean of your class, every time a new "message" comes in, it will be processed by the same instance of that class.

But that also means that you cannot have mutable instance variables in that singleton bean because the next call of a method of that class will see data from past calls..

Example:
Calculator is my bean (singleton)

```
public class Calculator {
 private List<String> operations = new ArrayList<String>();


public void calculate(String op, double val) {
 operations.add(op);
 // do some calculations
}


public List<String> getAllOperations() {
 return operations;
}

}
```

Here's the client (`useCalc` is invoked many times!):

```
public class CalculatorClient{

@Autowired
private Calculator calculator;

public void useCalc () {
  calculator.calculate("Add",100);
  calculator.calculate("Div",100);
  calculator.calculate("Diff",100);
  List<String> allOperations = calculator.getAllOperations();
// Do something..
}
}
```

So let's say CalculatorClient useCalc gets called several times with different operations..
eventually `operations` in `Calculator` will contain all of the operations ever done on that calculator.

So the question is this:

Is this Spring's limitation - not being able to effectively share information between methods within a class? And if it is so, how to share that kind of information between methods?

I know there is the prototype bean scope. Is that the only solution in this case?
BTW, prototype is not a solution here because with prototype a new class will get instantiated with every call to calculator:

```
  calculator.calculate("Add",100); // New 
  calculator.calculate("Div",100); // New
  calculator.calculate("Diff",100); // New
```

And since Singleton is the default scope - aren't developers inadvertently introduce such bugs?

Comment: Not everything needs to be a Spring bean. Your calculator for example doesn't need to be. And a stateless Spring bean can also act as a factory for stateful objects, if you need that.

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet but how to then instantiate avoiding `new`? Using `new` will result in managed and non-managed beans? Yeah, I think a factory is the only solution here then.. but inside factory I'll still have to use `new`..

Comment: And what's the problem with new? new is not inherently bad. It's problematic when it prevents you from injecting a mock dependencies in tests, or when you need to apply an advice or something like that. But your class is nothing more than a glorified ArrayList. And you create all your ArrayLists with new, don't you?

Comment: @JBNizet also, using `new` - where do I instantiate a `new Calculator()`? In the constructor of `CalculatorClient` won't do because `CalculatorClient` is itself a singleton bean.. If I don in the `calculate` method, how do I then share that instance with other methods within `CalculatorClient`?

Comment: You instantiate it in useCalc(). If you don't, then it will be called concurrently, by multiple threads handling requests and messages for several clients. If that's what you want, fine, but then it'd better be thread-safe and designed for that use-case.

Comment: @JBNizet the problem with `new` is yes - how to mock it? If you put it in a static factory, you need Powermock to mock that static method or to mock whenNew... And if you don't / can't use Powermock.. then it's a problem

Comment: If you need to mock it, inject a Spring bean acting as a factory for Calculator. In the test, use a mock factory that creates mock calculators.

Comment: Java 8 made that crazy simple; your "mock factory" can be as simple as `() -> mockCalculator`.

Comment: @JB Nizet "what's the problem with new" - the problem is that if you create a class with new, it will not be managed by Spring and no other `@Autowired` will work for that class

Answer (score 2):

A common use case for singleton beans are to inject services into other objects.

Example, to provide an object a service to connect to the database, you "autowire" a database connection bean.

You don't want to create a new instance of the database every time, so singleton beans make sense.

Usually, the object itself that uses the autowire is a singleton as well (in a web app, the Controllers are also created just once, you don't want to create a controller for every request).

> aren't developers inadvertently introduce such bugs?

Since the idea is to process several requests concurrently, all of those objects are usually already coded without having common state shared using instance variables.

This is not a "limitation", but rather a default for the most common use case.

> I know there is the prototype bean scope. Is that the only solution in this case?

It sounds like a good "solution" to this, in that case a new bean will be created. Note that it would not make sense to autowire a prototype bean into a singleton since in that case there will only be once instance anyway.

Another possibility more commonly used is autowiring a singleton bean that acts like a factory, then ask that factory for a new object each time you need one.

The factory can be a singleton since you don't want more than one factory, but it would then return new objects in every call to its "create" method.

So in your example, you could do something like

```
@Autowired
private CalculatorFactory calcFactory;

public void useCalc () {
   calculator = calcFactory.createCalculator();
   calculator.calculate("Add",100);
   calculator.calculate("Div",100);
   calculator.calculate("Diff",100);
   List<String> allOperations = calculator.getAllOperations();
   // Do something..
}
```

}

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the only possibility, but Factory doesn't always make sense.. just to create a new class. Factory is more when you have multiple options for various families of classes.. Merely wrapping `new` in a Factory looks like overkill?

Comment: Factory is for whenever you want to avoid calling "new" directly from your code, so it is indeed a valid use case here. You can also create a "new" calculator directly, but that would not let you inject a mock CalculatorFactory later on if you want to unit test this class.

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot of conflation going on here.  Let me try to unravel the premises.

The whole *point* of dependency injection is to make it so that you don't have *multiple* instances of a critical application service, which would lead to things getting out of sync or result in erratic behavior (e.g. multiple database connections, multiple access points to a JMS queue, multiple *ways* to query a database, etc).

It is ***not*** a mandate to make *everything* injectable.

If something is not inherently reusable, or you would not gain anything from registering it in the component scan, then there is no reason to make that thing either a bean or a component.

It is fairly reasonable to assume that beans *shouldn't* store state, but that doesn't mean that something else couldn't store that state on its behalf.  For instance, you could put those operations into some other backing store as opposed to in-memory, and you'd still be able to keep the state of operations you've done.

The big thing that I'm seeing is that you've kind of implemented your `Calculator` class half-thinking that it was a bean, and half-thinking that it was `new`ed up somewhere.  By having that list in your class, you're subconsciously forcing yourself to hold onto the state in any instance created, which violated the inversion of control principle - you don't control the lifecycle of the object.

To get around this...you have a few options available.

- Change how you're storing the state of your operations.  Put it into a SQLite database or a file or somewhere that isn't dependent on an instance maintaining it.
- Inject your *own*.  You can create a bean that is of type `List<String>`, and require your `Calculator` to inject it when it's needed.
- Don't create a bean.  You can `new` this and Spring isn't really going to fuss at you. It'd make it harder to test, though.

The first two approaches abstract away the notion of *storing* the data from an operation and *reading* the data from the operations.  You can either read from the injected operations bean or from the SQLite database or from the flat file to get the result of operations that you want.

Comment: Thank you @Makoto. Storing outside memory is not an option in this case. The only solutions I see - is storing it temporarily in the calling method (by making `calculate` return the operation just performed and storing it in a list within `CalculatorClient`, but then how to share across other methods within `CalculatorClient`?). Another option is to use `new` and this seems to be the only option. Yes, storing state within calculator is not a good candidate for a bean..  That means for example you can't use the Builder pattern as a spring bean.

Comment: @ACV:  I wouldn't know why you'd ever want to inject a builder.  I see literally no reason to do so, nor would I know what you'd accomplish, since a builder is effectively a factory which `new`s things up based on information provided.  There's zero wins you'd get from having a builder be a `Bean`.  You could probably make the output of your builder a `Bean`, but that's fairly conventional.

Comment: I think the conclusion here is if you use Spring - not everything should be a bean.